# Multi Questioning

Tags: python, replace

i read data from txt. 1st line is the row's labels and from 2nd to end the data.

Q1)how i can skip line 1?

the data is in form 34,5 and not 34.5 so i can't use float()
i try str.replace() with not success

Q2) any other idea or suggestion in conversion?

Q3)i use python through QGIS as script. any idea how interrupt the "running" of the script??

the code which i have write as now:

```
import string

X=[]
Y=[]
with open('D:/test_data/CLOUDS1.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        row = line.split()
        X.append(row[0])
        Y.append(row[1])
for i in X,Y:
     print i
for j in Y:
    j.replace(',' , '.')
    print j
```

Q4) how i can make a list of point from X,Y??

Comment: In the future, please search for questions before you ask them, since many of these are duplicates. Also, please stick to one or two questions per post.

Comment: it would be more helpfully to give an answer.
for making this post it means that already had search and check the answers.... but your only purpose was to make a comment to take the point. gratz

Comment: I gave an answer below before I made the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1

If you want to skip the first line, you have to read it from the buffer. If you don't need the column headings, just don't store the result into a variable:

```
with open('D:/test_data/CLOUDS1.txt') as f:
    f.readline() # Reads the first line but does not store the result
    content = f.readlines() # Reads the rest of the lines
```

### Question 2 and 4

Assuming your file content looks similar to

```
x_coord y_coord
23,4 45,6
15,6 24,1
65,2 96,03
```

When replacing parts of a string, the string is not changed in-place. You have to assign the result of the replace call to a new variable and use it:

```
points = []
for l in content:
    parts = l.split()
    x = float(parts[0].replace(',', '.'))
    y = float(parts[1].replace(',', '.'))
    points.append([x, y])
```

Or, in condensed form:

```
points = [[float(p.replace(',', '.')) for p in l.split()] for l in content]
```

The result in either case is a 2-dimensional list (i.e. a list of lists) where each element in the outer list is a list with 2 elements representing the `x` and `y` coordinates of your points:

```
[[23.4, 45.6], [15.6, 24.1], [65.2, 96.03]]
```

Comment: unfortunatly the result was the same with many..... no list, no replace....

Comment: Can you clarify on issues concerning the result? I don't get your point.

Comment: when i run mine program i use a print to see what replace did, and i get the same result with what i have read 34,23 for example.

the same happend using your code.... the comma "," still exist

Answer (score 0):

1.

Replace:

```
content = f.readlines()
for line in content:
```

With:

```
header = f.readline()
for line in f:
```

4.

```
zip(X,Y)
```